# move_uploaded_file not working in wordpress folder

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I am trying to upload the file inside wordpress folder (wp-content/themes/twenty-twelve/uploads/) it is failing everytime when I submit the form.

My form path (wp-content/themes/twenty-twelve/template-parts/form.php)

```
<form id="Form" method="post" action="/checkout/" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Proceed to Payment" id="FormSubmit" />
</form>
```

Checkout.php path(wp-content/themes/twenty-twelve/template-parts/checkout.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$Image   = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$Image  = implode(",",$_FILES['image']['name']);

$thisFile = $_FILES['image'];
$Image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$FileTmp = $thisFile['tmp_name'][0];

$sFileTypeArr= explode(".",$Image );
$sFileType = end($sFileTypeArr);
$randNo = date("ydhis");
$ImageFinal = "IMG_".$randNo.".".$sFileType;

$url = '/wp-content/themes/twenty-twelve';
$fileSavePath = $url."/uploads/";

$ImageFinalWithPath = $fileSavePath.$ImageFinal;
$upload_file = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $ImageFinalWithPath);

var_dump($upload_file);
}
```

Error: bool(false)

NOTE: I have checked the file permission, given full permission. I have also checked the max_file_size_upload and other setting of php.ini.

I am trying to upload one file at a time. It shows the error bool(false)

Comment: do you tried $upload_file = move_uploaded_file($FileTmp, $ImageFinalWithPath); INSTEAD OF $upload_file = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $ImageFinalWithPath); ???

Comment: secondly try absolute path for $url as your Checkout.php is in (wp-content/themes/twenty-twelve/template-parts/) folder

Answer (score 2):

You should use WordPress helpers

```
wp_upload_dir()
```

> Get an array containing the current upload directory’s path and url.

See [wp_upload_dir()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/) and [Determining Plugin and Content Directories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories).